# JsonIgnore Not Work With Swagger When Using NewtonSoft

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, swagger

I am Using `Asp.net core 5`, I stopped using `System.text.Json` for some reason and I use `NewtonSoft` and I changed all the namespaces, for example, to `[JsonIgnore]`, but my problem is that the properties that I ignored are still displayed in the swagger output.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class AddEmployeeDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int EmployeeType { get; set; }
}
```

this is swagger output :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6GOF.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Sytem.text.Json` has become the default `Serialize` tool of `Asp.Net Core`, the standard version of `Swagger` is also compatible with it,
and to change it, like this change that you have probably applied,
`services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();`

You must install the package From `Nuget`:

`Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft`

And register it in your Service Container as follows to solve your problem

`services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();`

Comment: Your answer is perfect !